# I'm trying to make the program provide the amount of quarts, gallons, and barrels based on the amount of oz entered by user

Tags: java

Here is the code I have so far. I can't figure out how to make quarts have an output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LiquidMeasures {
/**
    * Allows user to enter liquid values in ounces
    * and returns number of barrels, gallons, and quarts
    * based on the entered liquid ounces value.
    *
    * @param args Command line arguments - not used.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = ""; 
      int liquid = 0;
      int barrels = 0;
      int gallons = 0;
      int quarts = 0;
      int ounces = 0;


   //Prompt the user for amount of liquid in ounces:
      System.out.print("Enter amount of liquid in ounces:");
      liquid = userInput.nextInt();

      if (liquid % 32 == 0) { //if liquid ounces is divisible by 32
         System.out.print("");

      }

      else { 
         System.out.println("Amount must be a multiple of 32.");
      }

   //Prompt the user for measures by volume
      System.out.println("Measures by volume:");


   //Return number of barrels
      System.out.println("\tBarrels: ");


   //Return number of gallons
      System.out.println("\tGallons: ");


   //Return number of quarts
      System.out.println("\tQuarts: ");
```

and here's the output

```
Enter amount of liquid in ounces: 96
Measures by volume:
    Barrels: 
    Gallons: 
    Quarts:
```

Comment: First of all, you really need to fix the formatting on your post, your code is very difficult to read and understand. Second, The reason you're not outputting anything is because you've not doing any calculations, and you're not supplying the variable you want to output. You're basically just printing a bunch of labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an integer into a string and concatenate it onto another string with the `+` operator, i.e. `"this is a number: "+100` becomes `"this is a number 100"`